# Channel Info Tag - Two different channels

Tags: channel-entries, tags

Is it possible to deliver the channel info tag for two different channels?

I know the below does not work using a pipe separator.

{exp:channel:info channel="news|contact"} {channel_title} {/exp:channel:info}

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. There's no mention to multiples channels on [docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_info.html#parameters) and Boyink [talks about](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_info.html#9382) this case too.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but I believe that the [query module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/index.html) can help you:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT channel_title AS the_name_you_want_for_your_variable
    FROM exp_channels
    WHERE channel_name IN ('news','contact');"
}
    {the_name_you_want_for_your_variable}
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you, @Paul? If so, please, mark it as right.